# Populating an Array with recursive function of a class

Tags: php, arrays, function, class, recursion

I'm getting stuck with maybe a simple question. I created a new class with many calculations inside. I have a recursive array to dynamically generate SQL from a Die result. When the result is between a given range, I'll have to do an extra operation.

I've got this multi-dimensional array to fill with the value of my dice, using an array of IDs as my first "key":

```
$this->multidim[$id_object][]
```

I was thinking about creating another function to populate it, but I'm unsure how to build it correctly. The specifications of this function I need are the following:

- I need to call a function with the multidimensional array, and
- If the result is 100, I need to re-roll the dice twice, and check the result again

```
$this->checkresult($id_obj, $die);

function checkresult($id_obj, $die)
{
    if ($die == 100){

        $rand1 = $this->launchDie(1, 100);
        $rand2 = $this->launchDie(1, 100);

        if($this->checkresult($array, $rand1)) {
            if($this->checkresult($array, $rand2)) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (!isset($array[$tiro])) {
            $this->multidim[$id_obj][$die] = 1;
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Is this approach correct? I feel uncomfortable not returning a "real" value, but as I said I need to re-call that function recursively.

Comment: What is the code for `setSpecialCount()` and where do the variables `$array` and `$tiro` come from?

Comment: sorry, i forgotten to change my reference. editing right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the rolled value like this:

```
public function addResult($object_id, $result)
{
        $this->multidim[$object_id][] = $result;
}

public function checkResult($object_id)
{
        $roll = $this->launchDie(1, 100);

        if ($roll == 100) {
                $additionalRoll = $this->checkResult($object_id);
                $this->addResult($object_id, $additionalRoll);

                $roll = $this->checkResult();
        }

        return $roll;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
$this->addResult($object_id, $this->checkResult($object_id));
```

This way each time a 100 is rolled there will be two rolls instead of the one. Please note that this could go on forever (improbable, though ;)).

Also note that I changed the structure of your multidim array, as it made more sense to me that way, you may need to change that back if it doesn't match what you would like to achieve.